# How to use a home page for php and angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, redirect, url-routing

I am facing a bit of a challenging problem:

Our website has a home page, which has no uri parameters, and is just the domain name. When a user logs in, I also want to use the home page (no uri) for their login home page.

This would usually be fine with PHP because it would be a matter of checking the session – if they aren't logged in, show the public home page, else show the logged in home page. But, I want to use angular for the logged in part of the site.

Is there a way I can use the domain without any uri params for angular when the user is logged in, and for then the user isn't logged in?

I was thinking this COULD be a solution, to use

> http://www.theawesomesite.org.au/home (now public home)

instead of

> http://www.theawesomesite.org.au (now logged in home)

for the public home page, but then I would somehow have to redirect searches that come from google pages of users expecting to see the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your initial PHP script, check the `$_SESSION` variable that tracks whether the user is logged in. Then send the relevant page with readfile();

```
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    readfile("myLoggedInPage.html");
  } else {
    readfile("myNotLoggedInPage.html");
  }
```

If you need PHP functionality, use `include()` instead of `readfile()`

Comment: Is php able to read cookies that are set by angular? If not then this won't work, as I am setting the logged in state through angular.

Comment: Provided you're on the same domain for everything you should be able to read/write the cookies from PHP and Angular. Be careful with the cookie path. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196229/cant-delete-cookie-with-angularjss-cookies)