# Angular Cookies.remove not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have a scenario where I am adding a cookie using normal java-script and trying to retrieve it using angular Cookies service which is working fine. But the removal of the cookie using Cookies service is not working. My JS is like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngCookies']);
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window, $cookies) {
            $scope.ReadCookie = function () {
                $window.alert($cookies.get('username'));
            };
            $scope.RemoveCookie = function () {
                $cookies.remove('username');
            };

        });
         function addCookie(){
                document.cookie="username=John Doe;path=/";
            }
    </script>
```

My HTML is

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="button" value="Write Cookie" onclick="addCookie()"/>
        <input type="button" value="Read Cookie" ng-click="ReadCookie()" />
        <input type="button" value="Remove Cookie" ng-click="RemoveCookie()" />
    </div>
```

Is it related to the path of the cookie, if yes how can i mention the path in the remove function ?

Comment: You should use angular way of creating a new cookie. also check do you have <head> <base href="/"></head> in you html.

Answer (score 29):

Try with `{ path: YOUR_PATH }` as parameter.

For example, with `<base href="/">`,
put `$cookies.remove('username', { path: '/' });`

Comment: Yes, if you set it with a path option, remove it with a path option.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window, $cookies) {
    $scope.ReadCookie = function () {
        $window.alert($cookies.get('username'));
    };
    $scope.RemoveCookie = function () {
        $cookies.remove('username');
    };
    $scope.addCookie= function () {
        $cookies.put('username','John',[path:'/']);
    };

});
```

Comment: Actually I cannot add a cookie using angular. Its an existing scenario done by a servlet. All i need is the removal of the cookie.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196229/cant-delete-cookie-with-angularjss-cookies

Answer (score 0):

Setting default path worked for me:

```
$cookiesProvider.defaults.path = "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to the angular blocking me to delete the cookie from another `path` the trick that I have done to work-around it was to set the `expire` date from the cookie to `now` ¯_(ツ)_/¯ :

```
$cookies.put(cookieName, cookieValue, { expires: $window.moment().toString() });
```